# ehcache RMI replication in ubuntu with boot bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory

Tags: xml, ehcache

I am trying to RMI replicate ehcache on different machine on ubuntu.
I deploy ehcache war two instance of tomcat on various machine. 
and this is my ehcache.xml on both server.

```
 `<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
        properties="peerDiscovery=automatic,
                    multicastGroupAddress=230.0.0.1,
                    multicastGroupPort=4446, timeToLive=1"
        propertySeparator=","
        />
<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"/>

<defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120"
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"
        overflowToDisk="true"
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
        maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
        diskPersistent="false"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
        />
 <cache name="sampleCache1"
       maxElementsInMemory="10000"
       maxElementsOnDisk="1000"
       eternal="false"
       overflowToDisk="true"
       diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
       timeToIdleSeconds="300"
       timeToLiveSeconds="600"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
       transactionalMode="off"
        />
<cache name="sampleDistributedCache1"
       maxElementsInMemory="10"
       eternal="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="100"
       timeToLiveSeconds="100"
       overflowToDisk="false">

    <cacheEventListenerFactory
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"/>
    <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"/>
</cache>
<cache name="sampleDistributedCache2"
       maxElementsInMemory="10"
       eternal="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="100"
       timeToLiveSeconds="100"
       overflowToDisk="false">
    <cacheEventListenerFactory
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
            properties="replicateAsynchronously=false, replicatePuts=false,
                        replicatePutsViaCopy=false, replicateUpdates=true,
                        replicateUpdatesViaCopy=true, replicateRemovals=false"/>
</cache>
<cache name="sample/DistributedCache3"
       maxElementsInMemory="10"
       eternal="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="100"
       timeToLiveSeconds="100"
       overflowToDisk="true">
    <cacheEventListenerFactory
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
            properties="asynchronousReplicationIntervalMillis=200"/>
</cache>
```

When I start both instance of tomcat i got this kind of Error :

```
17:06:33.856 [Multicast keep-alive Heartbeat Receiver thread-1] DEBUG n.s.e.d.MulticastKeepaliveHeartbeatReceiver - Aborting processing of rmiUrls since failed to add rmiUrl: //127.0.1.1:38249/sample/DistributedCache3 17:06:38.855 [Multicast Heartbeat Receiver Thread] DEBUG n.s.e.d.MulticastKeepaliveHeartbeatReceiver - rmiUrls received //127.0.1.1:38249/sample/DistributedCache3|//127.0.1.1:38249/sampleDistribute Cache2|//127.0.1.1:38249/sampleDistributedCache1 17:06:38.855 [Multicast keep-alive Heartbeat Receiver thread-1] DEBUG n.s.e.d.RMICacheManagerPeerProvider - Lookup URL //127.0.1.1:38249/sample/DistributedCache3 17:06:38.855 [Multicast keep-alive Heartbeat Receiver thread-1] DEBUG n.s.e.d.MulticastRMICacheManagerPeerProvider - Unable to lookup remote cache peer for //127.0.1.1:38249/sample/DistributedCache3. Removing from peer list. Cause was: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```